# Как загрузить связанные таблицы в view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Допустим есть две модели:

```
public class Doctor
    {   
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FIO { get; set; }


        public int SpecialistId { get; set; }
        public Specialist Specialist { get; set; }
    }

public class Specialist
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Как написать в контроллере чтобы выводился в view что врач Иванов = терапевт, я делаю так: 
mymodel.Specialists = await _context.Specialists.ToListAsync(); у меня весь список специальностей выводится для Иванова

Comment: Ну так у Doctor есть свойство Specialist, просто выводите его значение

Comment: У меня для одного врача все специальности выводится

Comment: Спасибо, решил, помогло

Comment: Вам надо не _context.Specialists выводить, а doctor.Specialist